# I want my Processor to get access to JobExecutionId

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Spring 4.3 with Spring Batch 3.0.8.

I want to have a reference to the job execution id in the processor, so I can put it inside the output object and write it out along with the data to db.   Here is my setup below.

I have added the blueReportJobExecutionListener, which gives me the JobExecution ID that I need.... but how do I send that over to my blueReportItemProcessor ?!   That's the object that needs that value.

```
<bean id="blueReportJobExecutionListener" class="com.cloud.cost.listener.BlueReportJobExecutionListener" scope="prototype" />
<bean id="blueReportJobListener" class="com.cloud.cost.listener.BlueReportJobListener" scope="prototype" />
<bean id="blueReportStepListener" class="com.cloud.cost.listener.BlueReportStepListener" scope="prototype" />

<batch:job id="blueReportJob">
    <batch:step id="blueReportStep">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="blueReportCSVFileItemReader" processor="blueReportItemProcessor" writer="mysqlItemWriter"
                commit-interval="2">
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="blueReportStepListener"/>
        </batch:listeners>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="blueReportJobListener"/>
        <batch:listener ref="**blueReportJobExecutionListener**"/>
    </batch:listeners>
</batch:job>
```

Comment: I solved this by adding a value to the cacheManager we have in place.... still not understanding how to bridge this gap in a 'Spring-batch native' way....

Answer (score 0):

You can the get the value from Job Execution by simply using @Value annotation.

```
@Value("#{jobExecutionContext['JOB_ID']}")
```

Where JOB_ID is the key you have used in the listener to add the job id.

Make sure your processor scope is defined as step otherwise this value will not be autowired.